# Найти в диапазоне число начинающиеся и заканчивающиеся на 8

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит числа a и b , задающие диапазон [a;b]. В этом диапазоне нужно найти числа начинающиеся и заканчивающиеся на 8. Только через цикл while или for , превращать число в str нельзя.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124300/discussion-on-question-by-ellidan2019-------).

Answer (score 4):

По добру, надо делать так:

```
def isValid(num):
    digs = []
    while num > 0:
        digs.append(num % 10)
        num //= 10
    return digs[0] == 8 and digs[-1] == 8


print([i for i in range(int(input()), int(input()) + 1) if isValid(i)])
```

А если по приколу, то так:

```
import math
import operator

[  i for i in range(int(input()), int(input()) + 1) if all ( k == 8 for k in operator.itemgetter(0, -1)([ (i // (10 ** x) if x else i) % 10 for x in range(int(math.log10(i) + 1)) ]) )]
```

P.S. Слишком много промучался, чтобы написать это. Пожалуйста, не ставьте минус. Все ради азарта. И главное, все без `str()`

Comment: pep8 на вас нет)

Comment: @insolor, такие однострочные решения заставляют мозг думать логически.  Грех отказываться от такой задачки :))

Comment: Ну, я про неоднострочный вариант с отступами в 2 пробела)

Comment: @а, та это мне prettier плагин в вскоде автоматически форматирует.

Comment: Зачем `list comprehension` там, где явно `filter` напрашивается? )  Хотя короче не будет, потом опять в `list` превращать, но по сути то это именно фильтр функцией.

Comment: @CrazyElf, мне показалось так эффективнее всего будет.

Comment: @entithat Да наверняка и будет. Это просто лично мне не нравится эстетически конструкция `[i for i in ... if ...]`, по сути это же `list(filter(...))` в чистом виде. Но это вопрос личного вкуса, конечно, не обращайте внимание )